# Regex loop stops after 60 iterations

Tags: python, regex, for-loop

I'm trying to find a regex pattern and put it in a dataframe column, while looping over the values of another column.

Problem : It works wonders up until the 60th iteration but then it only shows NaN. I have 400 000 entries and most of them should match.

Why is that and how can I fix it?

```
import re

new_mail = []
for urlcore in re.finditer('https*://[www.]*(\S*).*\.(fr|com)',str(df['Site_Web'])):
    yolo = urlcore.group(1)
    new_mail.append(yolo)

df['urlcore'] = pd.Series(new_mail)
df['urlcore'] = df['urlcore'].str.replace('.', '', regex=True).replace('-', '', regex=True)
```

Comment: Have you tested the regex string above with one that should match and isn't? It may be that you need to modify the regex.

Comment: your regex expression looks weird , [www.] mach with `waaaaabbb` `abb,` `-----.`` and the part in the core (\S*). match wit someting lik this `google-------------------.com`

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show three rows in `df['Site_Web']`

Comment: try to use `https*:\/\/(www\.)?.*\.(fr|com)`

Comment: ThomasAyoub you need use the `?` in the `https?` because the `*` match with httpssss

Comment: @Nick, when testing the regex for individual values, it works.

Comment: @Gytree, should I replace [www.] with (www.) ? I want the core of the url which is between https*://www. (or https*://) and the extension.

Comment: @Thomas Ayoub, thanks but I still have the same issue

Comment: why do you need to change the df['Site_web'] to a string ?

Comment: @Gytree otherwise I have an "expected string or bytes-like object" error

Comment: What's the value off the `df['Site_Web']` when the regex stops working?

Answer (score 0):

Your regex suffer from performance issues due to `(\S*).*`. Change it to `https?:\/\/(www\.)?(\S*)\.(fr|com)`

Answer (score -2):

the correct regular expression for that it's:

```
(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61})\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}
```

note that you have three unnamed groups in the regular expression but the first and the second don't be capture, so for access to the core part should be urlcore.group(1)

[image]

in your case you need to change the end part for (fr|com) and if you need to handle sub-domains also need to modify the regex to handle a previous optional group `(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}\.)*`